# Simple react state not changing on first request

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure why but for some reason in this simple demo you have to submit the form twice in order to change the value of `testState`. What should happen is whenever you submit the form (the first time), `testState` should change its value to `"changed"`, but it only appears to happen on the second, third (and so on) submits.

Can anyone spot anything obvious here? Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [testState, setTestState] = useState("unset");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const submitMe = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTestState("changed");
    console.log("name change Fn", inputValue, 'testState', testState); // should log 'changed' after first submit
  };

  const onNameChange = e => {
    console.log(e)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={submitMe}>
        <input
          placeholder="the value"
          type="text"
          onChange={e => onNameChange(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And a stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-joe6jg

The value should log to the console with form submits.

Thank you.

Comment: State is updated asynchronously. Use `useEffect` hook to log the updated state. Logging the state immediately after calling state updater function will log the old value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the explaination in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
> pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
> method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
> and calls may be batched for performance gains.

You should monitor state changes inside useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [testState, setTestState] = useState("unset");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const submitMe = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTestState("changed");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("name change Fn", inputValue, "testState", testState);
  }, [inputValue, testState]);

  const onNameChange = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={submitMe}>
        <input
          placeholder="the value"
          type="text"
          onChange={e => onNameChange(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the updated state immediately after set state.
You need to get it by `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(testState)
}, [testState]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`useState`s set method is asynchronous in a way. So only after current scoped code is finished your variable will trigger change in component and then it you can log it. you can try by putting `console.log` in component (not in `useEffect`) and see how your component changes.

But also you can see it also inside `useEffect` so that logging does not trigger on every rerender:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(testState)
}, [testState]);
```